# How to take changes from one git branch to another branch

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

I have the below branches.

> Branch A : The main branch or the master branch.
>
> Branch B : Created from A.
>
> Branch C : Created from B.
>
> Branch D : Created from A

Now I did some changes to branch C and now I could merge them to branch B. But at this moment a new branch D is created from branch A and now I should merge my changes to branch D. How to take all of my changes to branch D ? Since I have lots of commits I can not cherry-pick them one by one. I tried to rebase branch D on branch C, but I am getting lots of conflicts which I can't resolve manually. So what is the best way to merge branch C to branch D ?

EDIT 1 :

Let me clarify my problem a bit more. Here branch A is the master branch. Branch B is a release branch (which has just ended, so the branch is now in active). Branch C is my topic branch cut from B, branch D is the new release branch cut from A. Ideally we should merge our topic branch only to the release branch and cherry pick those changes to the master branch (A).So we create a topic branch from the current release branch then do our changes and raise merge request. We should not add anything to the inactive release branch. Now I was working on a branch C which was cut from a release branch B which has become inactive. Now I should create a branch from D and add all my changes there and raise one Merge Request. I don't want to do that. I want to use my branch C to raise a Merge Request on branch D which will not have any conflict. Is it possible ?

My solution is :

I would create a temporary branch B_temp out of branch B. Squash merge my topic branch C to B_temp. Then create a new branch E out of D, cherry pick the commit from B_temp to branch E, resolve any merge conflict (I can resolve those as they are my changes only). Raise merge request for F onto branch D. I am wondering if there is any better solution available instead of creating new branches and cherry picking if I could simply use the old branch C.

Note : We are not allowed to merge anything in the master and release branches without proper Merge Request and approval.

Comment: What is wrong with creating a merge request from branchC into branchD directly?

Comment: And if branchB is a completed release branch will it ever be merged into master?

Comment: I want to create MR from branchC to branchD directly, but branchC is created from branchB, so how to get the changes of branchD into branchC first, if i do rebase of brachD into branchC it gives lots of conflicts. Thats the problem. 
branchB never merges to master instead each commit in branchB is cherry picked to master. That is we squash merge our topic branch to release branch and that single commit gets cherry picked to master.

Comment: What does MR mean?

Comment: "if i do rebase of brachD into branchC it gives lots of conflicts." That is probably because both `branchC` and `branchD` modify the same files. When you rebase, you have to edit the files as appropriate to resolve these conflicts.

Comment: MR : merge request

Answer (score 1):

Assume the commit history for all branches as below:

```
...---A---...---G   branchA, branchD
       \
        B---C---D---M   branchB
             \     /
              E---F branchC
```

There usually has two ways to merge changes from `branchC` to `branchD`.

#### Option 1: merge branchB into branchD

Since you have merged `branchC` into `branchB`, so you can merge `branchB` into `branchD`, and then the changes from `branchC` will be applied to `branchD`:

```
git checkout branchD
git merge branchB
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
             branchA
                |
...---A---...---G-----H   branchD
       \             /
        B---C---D---M   branchB
             \     /
              E---F branchC
```

#### Option 2: rebase branchC onto branchA, then merge into branchD

Or you can rebase `branchC` onto `branchA` firstly by:

```
git rebase --onto branchA branchB branchC
```

And the commit history will be:

```
                  E'---F' branchC
                 /
...---A---...---G    branchA, branchD
       \
        B---C---D---M   branchB
             \     /
              E---F
```

Then merge the rebased `branchC` into `branchD`:

```
git checkout branchD
git merge branchC
```

And the commit history will be:

```
              branchA
                |
...---A---...---G---E'---F'    branchC, branchD
       \
        B---C---D---M   branchB
             \     /
              E---F
```

---

> I want to use my branch C to raise a Merge Request on branch D which
>   will not have any conflict. Is it possible ?

Yes, it possible.
First, please check if there has file(s) which was changes both in `branchC` and `branchD` by:

```
git diff branchC branchD --name-only
```

- If there has no files changed in both sides, then create a merge request to merge `branchC` into `branchD` directly.
- Else, overwrite the conflict file version in branchC by using branchD's file version:

  ```
  git checkout branchC
  git checkout branchD -- filename
  git commit -m 'overwrite the filename by using the version from branchD'
  git push origin branchC
  ```

  Then create a merge request to merge `branchC` into `branchD`, and there won't has merge confilcts.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I added few more details of my problem to the question. Can you please suggest me how to resolve the particular problem.

Comment: @saurav I added the way to merge `branchC` into `branchD` without merging conflicts in the end of my answer. And you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. I was also doing the same, but the problem comes when there are a ton of files which have changes. Its impossible to checkout them individually from branch D. So I was wondering if there exists any other shortcut.

Comment: git commit -m 'overwrite the filename by using the version from branchD' 
won't this make me the owner of the changed files ? I don't want this .  I maybe wrong here.

Comment: @saurav If so, you can checkout all the files' version from `branchD` to `branchC` by executing `git checkout branchD -- .` on `branchC`, then change and commit part of files as you want on `branchC`.